# Google Maps Geocode - Results relevance

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the basic functionality of Google Maps Javascript API

Code sample from google :

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple

```
var geocoder;
var map;
function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}

function codeAddress() {
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

So as you can tell, when we type a street name, even if we have several results, the sample above is just showing one. I already changed that to loop throught all results and it works fine.

My questions are:

The `geocoder.geocode` **results** are sorted by any criteria?

If the answer is yes, is it possible to get the results sorted by most relevant / near place of the current user location ? (I will pass the current user location).

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you asking if you can sort the results by distance from the current location of the user?  If so, yes you can.

Comment: Hi ! The first question is : When I get more than one result, that array is sorted by relevance or something else? Regarding the second question I don't want to manually sort that list, I would like to know if google has any option for you to tell : Geocode this address having in account my current location. Because if you search something like : "liberty road", there are several roads across the globe, so I would like to get the nearest "liberty road".

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong API for this, try using the Google Places API. This sorts by popularity (preferred).

Or you can use some code to loop through the results and find the distance from the original location. Then you can sort by distance (works, but I think popularity is what you want)

Answer (score 0):

Closest thing that I know off is using region biasing: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#RegionCodes